# Virtual or Soft Keyboard slows down speed of OS

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on soft keyboard where I am successfully replacing the
current default device keyboard with my soft keyboard.
**But the problem is, that after a couple of utilization's the full keyboard became blank and the phone Operating System started to run very slow. I had to shut down the keyboard app to make the phone work properly again.**

As I had used KeyboardView and in keyboardview I had used paint, canvas, bitmap which is called frequently by OS.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
rect = new RectF(x2+4, y2+4, ((width-4)+(x2+4)), ((height-10)+(y2+4)));
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 3, 3, paint2);
canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), x2 + (float)(width * 0.40), y2 + (float)(height * 0.7), paint);
canvas.drawText(smallAlphaText[index], x2 + (float)(width * 0.15), y2 + (float)(height * 0.30), paint3);
canvas.drawText(smallBetaText[index], x2 + (float)(width * 0.80), y2 + (float)(height * 0.30), paint4);
}
```

> This is the small code snippet showing what actually i have used.
>
> **Basically onDraw() is called again and again by OS, so although i replaced my soft  keyboard with default keyboard it running at 
>   background and slows down the speed of device**
>
> I think this is the issue which slows down speed of my phone.  So
>   how can I use paint, canvas, bitmap efficiently so that it doesn't
>   slow down my device?

Comment: what about posting some code?

Comment: @MisterSmith i have added some code snippet here...

Comment: Well, certainly there's room for optimization in that snippet. You could cache all the calcs, since the results are the same each time. But I think most phones, even crappy ones, can crunch those calculations without lagging. The problem must be in other point.

Comment: Have you faced this kind of problems? What exact problems are you talking about in other point.

Comment: A good mantra to follow when drawing is in the onDraw method, just draw. Don't do anything else. Shapes, paints, strings, all that should be done elsewhere.

Comment: Hey Phix i have taken a common code as possible out of onDraw(), i have just taken dynamically required code in onDraw block....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi I found problem due to which my device is lagging.
>
> I am calling my service from activity class. As if this is working on
>   newer version devices.
>
> But my device is lagging when I try to change my soft keyboard device
>   default keyboard.
>
> Earlier I tried below code I written this code in my activity class,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SoftKeyboard.class);
    startService(intent);
    finish();
```

> As we can see in above code I am trying to start service.
>
> Now I just skipped first two lines, so now it's systems responsibility
>   to call service.